# SQL query, select row based on another row

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a photo review application, SQL Server 2008 R2 back-end. One requirement is to me able to mark photos with anomalies such as "bad lighting," "blurry," etc. Another option is "Unidentified."

Whenever the user chooses "Unidentified," they are required to add an additional anomaly, called "Other," and give it a description. They can have the "Other" anomaly without the "Unidentified," but not vice versa.

I need to create a report that lists all the "Other" anomalies, if the picture also has the "Unidentified" anomaly. No idea how to write a query that accomplishes this. Basically the table has a photoID, and the anomalyID, and a description text field for "other," if required (plus some other irrelevant stuff).

So, the psuedocode would be:

Select PhotoID, Description from photo_anomalies 
where photo  anomaly "other" description is not null,
but only if there is a matching "unidentified" anomaly for that photoID.

clear as mud?

Comment: It is not clear how many tables are involved in the query and schema.

Comment: For this purpose, lets just assume one table, to make it simpler. The same photo can be there multiple times, with only some photos have a matching "Unidentified/Other" pair.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution - not sure if it's the best but it seems to work. Using a select where = "unidentified" inner joined on the PhotoID with a select where = "Other."